# Unable to connect to minikube from my local

Tags: docker, minikube

I am facing an issue with running minikube with driver as docker on Macbook M1. There are some network issues that I am running into. I am not able to ping into my minikube from my local machine and hence I whenever i am exposing a service in a nodeport mode, it is not accessible on node IP(i.e., minikube ip with the port extension) from the browser.

I tried changing the driver to hyperkit or virtualbox but it says

> minikube v1.32.0 on Darwin 14.2.1 (arm64)
> Using the hyperkit driver based on user configuration
> Exiting due to DRV_UNSUPPORTED_OS: The driver 'hyperkit' is not supported on darwin/arm64"

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you get the same error when using virtualbox instead of hyperkit?

Comment: Yes, the exact same error in case of virtualbox too

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, VirtualBox doesn't support darwin/arm64, it is still in beta without any shipping date confirmed : https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=107344

I recommend you go with QEMU driver which is stable :

```
minikube start --driver=qemu
```

Also, if the driver problem is solved you should investigate using a port-forwarding to access it locally :

```
kubectl port-forward service/[service_name] 7080:8080
```

Then just go to localhost:7080

Or, you can simply execute the following and minikube 'should' take care of it for you :

```
minikube service [service_name]
```